# How to write a sql statement to get a value from all users?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql statement like so

`select users.id, users.username, count(orders.number) as units from users inner join orders on orders.user_id = users.id where users.id = 1;`

Now this would the number or units user id one has made.

How do i get all users and the number or units they have purchased. The where keyword expects a value and a specific one, how can i say all users.

Thank you very much for reading this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need all users, remove where clause and group by user id

```
select users.id, users.username, count(orders.number) as units 
from users inner join orders 
on orders.user_id = users.id 
group by users.id,users.username;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `GROUP BY`:

```
     SELECT users.id, users.username, count(orders.number) as units 
     FROM users 
     INNER JOIN orders on orders.user_id = users.id 
     GROUP BY users.id, users.username
```

You can check more here: [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to aggregate the data, to do so use GROUP BY

```
        SELECT
        users.id, 
        users.username,
        count(orders.number) as units 
        FROM users  
        JOIN orders 
        ON orders.user_id = users.id
        GROUP BY users.id, users.username;
```

Check out the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) in here

Comment: What's the reasoning behind your indentation style?  I'd imagine it would be better if `FROM`, `JOIN`, `ON`, and `GROUP BY` were at the same indentation as `SELECT`.